# Nativescript - having a scrollView in a GridLayout not working on iOS

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to create a layout that has a button row at the top and then a scrollView beneath that:

```
<GridLayout columns="*,40,10" rows="10,40,*">
    <Label row="1" col="1" text="X" tap="close" />

    <ScrollView orientation="vertical" col="0" row="2" colSpan="3">
        …
    </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

This works on Android, I get a ScrollView that's 50 from the top and the Label with the «X» in it on top.
On iOS, the ScrollView always is at the top of the view, overlapping the «X»-Label.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

NS 8.x

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you have two rows but reference them as 1 and 2 rather than 0 and 1.

Comment: interesting - the above is pseudo-code, but I'll give it a shot